# How to push/pull columns to be on top in foundation for mobile?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have something like this in desktop

```
[Column1 large-8] [Column2 large-4]
```

In mobile I want

```
[Column2 large-4]
[Column1 large-8]
```

Here's my snippet

```
<div id="search-content" class="row main-content">

    <div class="columns large-8">

    </div>

    <aside class="columns large-4">

    </aside>

</div>
```

When I tried this

```
<div id="search-content" class="row main-content">

    <div class="columns large-8 small-push-4">

    </div>

    <aside class="columns large-4 small-pull-4">

    </aside>

</div>
```

It's doing something like this

```
[Column2 large-4 small-pull-4][Column1 large-8 small-push-4]
```

And `Column2` something is pushed off the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

change your `small-pull-4` to `small-pull-8`

You should push your columns by `4` as you need `four column` space for first div
and `pull 8` as your first column is occupying `8 columns`

```
<div id="search-content" class="row main-content">
    <div class="columns large-8 small-push-4">
    </div>
    <aside class="columns large-4 small-pull-8">
    </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Push and Pull works with float elements.

You have to use jQuery, eg:

```
$('.col1').before($('.col2'));
```